# Small Seal Request

Tags: characters, seal

I am currenly looking for the small seal character for the words 生 (Sheng) and 智 (Hui)? Which I cannot find in the wiktionary.

Comment: `智 (Hui)` 智 is **zhì**. Maybe you're looking for 慧...

Comment: Go to zdic.net, look up the character, and click on 字源字形。

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Each character are written by 吴让之 and the whole picture is made [here](http://www.sfzd.cn/jizi.php).

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want to convert them to small seal characters?
If so, you can use this [converter](http://www.diyiziti.com/Builder/69).
If you do not know a lot of Chinese yet, just enter the Chinese words you want to convert in the big box next to "内容", then hit the button shows "在线转换" (with 2 arrows goes around each other, looks like a refresh icon, on the left of the texts). Then you should get small seal characters (小篆).